# why are // calculations faster the / calculations(or not)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I was just experimenting with some code and I found something out what makes no sence to me

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("524288000/1024/1024")
0.05489620000000173
>>> timeit.timeit("524288000//1024//1024")
0.030612500000017917
>>>
```

using // in calculations is faster then / calculations

but when i repeated it this where the results:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("524288000//1024//1024")
0.02494899999999234
>>> timeit.timeit("524288000/1024/1024")
0.02480830000001788
```

and now is / faster then // what makes no sense to me

why is this?

## edit:

the results of the experiment with the the amount of times repeated on 10000 this are the results:

```
avg for /: 0.0261193088
avg for //: 0.025788395899999896
```

Comment: CPUs these days can execute millions of instructions per second, so always there will be time variation, you can't tell `//` is faster than `/` always. Depends on the CPU hardware.

Comment: Maybe you did the first experiment when your OS was finishing an antivirus scan. Unless you can reliably reproduce this, there is nothing to explain. I, for one, can't reproduce what you first observed.

Comment: Moreover, you cannot literally predict what happens within nanoseconds, even a small variation in electron motion can produce delays, conclusions can be made if this result is constanly observed and variations are large enough. Try to do same 100000 times. Maybe you would observe some differences.

Comment: When experimenting with execution time you should use it to a larger scale (run many time the experiment) to get a more stable estimation (which does not invalidate the previous comments).

Comment: I have tried it 100 times

Comment: first time // faster second time /

Comment: 50 times this way around 50 times the other way around

Comment: so // firts and then /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you time a function the CPU calculates the difference between the time when the instruction finished and the time when the instruction started, but a lot happens under the hood and not just the algorithm that you're timing.

Try to read some books about Operating Systems and you'll understand better.

In order to do these kind of experiments you should repeat this algorithm thousands of times to escape from variations.

Try the code below, but if you want to do real experiments change the loop value to something greater

```
import timeit

loops = 100    

oneSlashAvg = 0
for i in range(loops):
    oneSlashAvg += timeit.timeit("524288000/1024/1024")
print(oneSlashAvg/loops)

doubleSlashAvg = 0
for i in range(loops):
    doubleSlashAvg += timeit.timeit("524288000//1024//1024")
print(doubleSlashAvg/loops)
```

Comment: This cannot be actually considered, because if operands are same, there is no gaurentee that the operation is executed always, an intellignet compiler would substitue the result directly upon seeing the constant operands. Results can be better if the operands are generated randomly for each iteration.

Comment: @NarasimhaPrasannaHN yeah if you have something better you can give us an example right?